# How to access NSURLResponse in ViewController

Tags: objective-c

Questions about the request to the server.

There is a class WebApi to communicate with the server, the controller calls the instance method WebApi.

There simply create a query and connect to a specified address.
When the connection has finished loading

```
- (Void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection
{
     _jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: response options: 0 error: nil];
}
```

How do I know in the controller that the property `(NSArray *) _jsonData` WebApi class contains the downloaded response, that is, how to understand when you can use the data stored in `_jsonData` inside the ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
We need to create a protocol within the WebAPI.

```
@protocol ProtocolWebResponse

@required

  -(void)updateDataPromoInTheController:(NSDictionary *)response;

@end
```

In WebAPI create function initWithDelegate

```
  - (id) initWithDelegate:(id)delegate
```

{

```
self = [super init];
if(self !=nil) {
    //As a delegate set our controller
    self.delegate = delegate;
}
return self;
```

}

Also in WebApi class

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

{

```
   _jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:nil];
    if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ProtocolWebResponse)]) 
    {
         [self.delegate updateDataPromoInTheController:_jsonData];
    }
```

}

Implement the protocol in the Controller class.

```
- (void)updateDataPromoInTheController:(NSDictionary *)response
```

{

```
   self.response = response;
```

}